# Предмет исследования?

Tags: этимология

Я не сразу разобрался со структурой "исследования". Это вопрос относится к исследованию "Почему Блаженный Августин имеет такой эпитет".

> Если у кого-то есть вопросы по данной теме готов на них ответить, по мере своих возможностей.

Знаете, на любой защите принято обозначать цель и инструмент исследования - и выводы, выносимые на защиту.

Начнем хотя бы с цели. Что собственно тут исследуется? Автор внятно не сформулировал.

Любое исследование, как мне представляется, заключается в постановке вопроса и ответа на него. Если считать что основным вопросом здесь является тот, что вынесен в заголовок, то ответ на него банален. Потому, что он достоин этого звания. Вопрос в веденьи церкви. К русскому языку этот нимало не относится.

Если же вопрос в том, почему в православии и католицизме этот термин понимается по-разному (на что есть намек в развернутом описании темы исследования), то тут можно спорить до бесконечности, вопрос остался открытым. Так уж сложилось.

Ну и наконец, если ставить вопрос о том, кого в православии считать блаженным, то тут тоже прямой ответ не дан. Ибо на самом деле в БТС изложено вплоне разумное определение. При чем тут "мнение еретиков" *)- совершенно непонятно.

*) кто это, кстати, в понимании автора? - вопрос риторический, знаю, что ответа не будет, видимо, их спутали с атеистами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема исследования - по какой причине Августин получил эпитет Блаженный. По отношению к данному святому термин употреблён в нехарактерном  в православной литературе значении. Соответственно вопрос к лингвистике имеет самое непосредственное значение.

> При чем тут "мнение еретиков" *)-
> совершенно непонятно.

После Великой Схизмы обе церкви предали друг друга анафеме и объявили друг друга еретиками ( по церковным представления - вероотступники, последователи еретического учения). Соответственно мнение одной церкви о том или ином святом вряд ли могло повлиять на мнение другой. Николай Мир Ликийских (Чудотворец) почитается обеими церквями, но эпитета Блаженный у него нет.
Слово "еретики" закавычено, что как раз и означает, что ни тех ни других я сам еретиками не считаю. Причём тут атеисты, я не знаю. Сам я, кстати, из их числа.

Различие в понимании слово блаженный в православной и католической церквях, необходимо было указать, так как есть версия, что как раз под влиянием католической беатификации эпитет и закрепился за Августином.

Comment: >Тема исследования - по какой причине Августин получил эпитет Блаженный.  
  
И почему же? Ответ на такой вопрос предполагает описание его деяний из жития святых, нет? 

>После Великой Схизмы...  
     
Да знаю я про схизму, Вы бы мне объяcнили, каким образом еретики в ваш текст про определение блаженного прокрались - и какое отношение имеют к советским энциклопедиям, составляемым **безожниками** - а потому по определению не могущими быть еретиками.

Comment: >как раз под влиянием католической беатификации эпитет и закрепился за Августином  
  
Вот те на. И кто эту версию высказывал? Сами же про схизму пишите.
Я лично говорил совершенно другое. Что все святые, канонизированные до 1052 г. (не наврал?) одинаково признаются обоими церквами.
Другое дело, что тут я погорячился, формально канонизация Августина состоялась только в XIX веке.

Вообще почти на все подобные вопросы ответы есть в интернете.
У Кураева, хотя бы (хоть и не люблю я этого комсомольского вождя)
http://kuraev.ru/smf/index.php?topic=31555.0
(особо - Ответ #18 : 27.05.2007, 15:19:31)

Comment: Как раз его жизнеописание не соответствует, тому, чтобы называть Блаженным, поэтому давать ссылку на это не вижу особого смысла. Хотя в принципе соглашусь, и лишним тоже не будет.

Меня интересует вопрос не **как** называют Августина, а **почему** его так называют. По Кузнецову (не знаю его вероисповедания, что, впрочем, не имеет никакого значения) Блаженный - "традиционный эпитет святого, одинаково почитаемого православной и католической церковью". Что во-первых; несовсем верно (есть и восточные Блаженные, не юродивые), а во-вторых; уводит в сторону от причины наименования.

Comment: >И кто эту версию высказывал?

Например, [агиографический словарь](http://www.patriarchia.ru/db/text/37374.html) Причина, по которой мне версия не нравится, я уже описал. Августин был признаваем святым ещё до раскола церкви. В XIX веке его лишь внесли в месяцеслов.

У Кураева в обсуждении, кстати, мусолят именно эту версию.

Comment: > агиографический словарь 
Я решительно не вижу там чего-то противоречащего 
Более того я готов подписаться под каждым словом из этой статьи.
Что Вам там не нравится?  
==
>Августин был признаваем святым ещё до раскола церкви  
  
Юридически - нет. Канонизирован в XIX веке, при чем тут  месяцеслов? С месяцесловом наша церковь до сих пор не разберется, то добавляют туда святых десятками, то вычеркивания. Месяцеслов - это всего лишь *дни почитания*.  

Для меня это тоже новость, но увы... Правда это никак не связано с обсуждаемым вопросм.

Comment: Суть в том, что вы какую-то надуманную (придуманную?) версию решили опровергать, а от от самоочевидной отвернулись. Он блаженный уже потому, что таковым его признает церковь. Что ешё надо-то? Установить, почему она таковым признает? Читайте житие. Я тут не знаток, но вполне доверяю.

Comment: Вот вы готовы подписаться, а мне версия не нравится. Причины я уже описал. В XIX веке канонизация была подтверждена. Блаженным Августин назывался и до этого. Как свидетеля православной веры Августина упоминает ещё Марк Эфесский на Фераро-Флорентийском соборе (1439-1440) В Синаксарий Никодима Святогорца (XVIII век) он также уже включён именно с этим наименованием.